# Can use map on this since it cant have duplicate keys when adding nodes

Tags: apex

Given 100 nodes in a Network; nodes starting from 0, 1... so on.
[0, 1, 2...] total 100 nodes.

Apex class with two methods:

connect(Integer source, Integer destination)
This method should connect passed nodes in the network.

isConnected(Integer source, Integer destination )
This should return true if destination can reach source, via any connections, implicitly or explicitly.

EX:

connect(2, 4);
connect(4, 9);
connect(10, 12);

then this should be the result:

isConnected(2, 4) will return true; // Explicitly connected; 6 is connected to 2.

isConnected(2, 9) will return true; // Implicitly connected; 9 is connected to 4 and 4 is connected to 2.

isConnected(9, 12) will return false;

isConnected(50, 99) will return false;

Comment: it is not clear what kind of question you have.Can you please elaborate it? It does sound like a question from job interview.

Comment: Please do not change your questions in a way that invalidates the answers that have been posted. Please do always show us your efforts so far to solve the problem. See [ask] and [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *recursive algorithm* problem. In order to solve it, you need to understand how to travel recursively.

In order to do this, you need to keep track of where you started, where you're trying to get to, where you are right now, and where you've been before (in order to avoid infinite loops).

One possible solution to this problem looks like this:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> connections = new Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>{
    2 => new Set<Integer>{6},
    6 => new Set<Integer>{9}
};

Boolean isConnected(Integer source, Integer destination) {
    return discoverPaths(source, destination, source, new Set<Integer>());
}
Boolean discoverPaths(Integer source, Integer destination, Integer current, Set<Integer> explored) {
    Set<Integer> localConnected = connections.get(current);
    if(localConnected == null) { // We're not on a path
        return false;
    }
    if(localConnected.contains(destination)) { // We found the end
        return true;
    }
    for(Integer nextElement: localConnected) {
        if(explored.add(nextElement)) { // Treading new paths
            if(discoverPaths(source, destination, nextElement, explored)) { // Call recursively
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

We first check to see if we're on a possible path, and go back to the previous item in the list if not. Then, we see if we reached the destination, and if so, we report that. This will be passed back up recursively. Finally, we test each connection to see if any of those paths lead to the destination. We do this recursively, so even a chain of 10 or 15 indirect connections will be detected correctly.

This solution isn't necessarily the most optimal solution, and it doesn't directly tell you the connected path, only that such a connection exists, but it does meet the parameters of this question.